# ID3D11Device::CreateVertexShader throws [ ERROR STATE_CREATION #167: CREATEVERTEXSHADER_INVALIDSHADERTYPE ]

Tags: c++, directx-11, vertex-shader

I have 2D video coordinates (x, y) to render lines to view window. At runtime ID3D11Device::CreateVertexShader throws exception [ ERROR STATE_CREATION #167: CREATEVERTEXSHADER_INVALIDSHADERTYPE ]

I have tried modifying input layout and structure but it looks expected to me. I can't pinpoint the actual reason of the exception regarding my situation.

```
/// <summary>Direct3D input layout for 2D position vertex. </summary>
static D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC Pos2DVertexLayout[] =
{
    {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
};

struct PSClipPosColor
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 depth : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 clipPos : TEXCOORD1;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

DirectX::XMFLOAT4 fixedColor {0, 0, 0, 1};

PSClipPosColor main(float2 position : POSITION0)
{
    PSClipPosColor output = (PSClipPosColor)0;

    float4 pos = float4(position, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    output.position = mul(pos, worldViewProjection);
    output.depth.xy = output.position.zw;
    output.color = fixedColor;
    output.clipPos = mul(pos, world);

    return output;
}
```

I am expecting the vertex shader should take 2D video coordinate position value for the input layout described. But instead throws exception [ ERROR STATE_CREATION #167: CREATEVERTEXSHADER_INVALIDSHADERTYPE ]

Please someone help me to find out where is the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found my problem location. It's silly.

Inside *.vcxproj file I have declared manually the variable name for PS to VS and VS to PS.

Was:

```
<FxCompile Include="Shaders\DrawLinesElementPS.hlsl"> 
  <ShaderType>Pixel</ShaderType>
  <VariableName>drawLinesElementVS</VariableName>
</FxCompile>
<FxCompile Include="Shaders\DrawLinesElementVS.hlsl">
  <VariableName>drawLinesElementPS</VariableName>
</FxCompile>
```

Now:

```
<FxCompile Include="Shaders\DrawLinesElementPS.hlsl"> 
  <ShaderType>Pixel</ShaderType>
  <VariableName>drawLinesElementPS</VariableName>
</FxCompile>
<FxCompile Include="Shaders\DrawLinesElementVS.hlsl">
  <VariableName>drawLinesElementVS</VariableName>
</FxCompile>
```